# Edit suggested on Late Answers queue

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, late-answers

I was reviewing the Late Answers queue when I saw the following for [I want to split string without using split function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26277790/1983854):

> [image]

That is, an answer having a suggested edit to be reviewed ([link to the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5958035)). It was clear to me that the edit was needed. I agreed on the suggested one, so I clicked on `edit (1)` and accepted the proposal.

I thought I would be redirected back to the Late Answers queue to continue reviewing the original answer, but that did not happen. Instead, I was shown the next post in the Suggested Edits queue.

I then clicked in the browser to go to that Late Answer again. I had contributed to edit the answer (by accepting the suggested edit), but still could not click in "I'm done". I figured out the system needed another action from me: adding a comment, up/downvoting or flagging. As any of these looked necessary to me, I just had to skip, because I thought it was not true to select "No Action Needed".

So my questions are:

- What is the desired behaviour after reviewing a suggested edit in the Late Answers queue? Shouldn't the system redirect us back to the Late Answers queue, instead of staying in the Suggested Edits?
- Shouldn't accepting an edit be enough action to say "I'm done"?

Comment: When I come to these scenarios I improve edit or reject and edit, then return with my newly placed edit and I'm Done enabled.

Comment: In this case I was the second to accept the suggested edit, so that it was still in the queue after my click.

Comment: No, my point is that by choosing an action which binds an edit from Community User, the review task is done and the post gets the improvement it needs, moreover the button is enabled. Whether reviewing the edit on the question should be sufficient for a Late Answer review task is another case.

Comment: Yes, that is my point: I consider that this should be the behaviour, but currently it is not. After accepting the suggested edit, I was sent to the Suggested edits queue. And when I clicked back, the "I'm done" button was still unclickable.

Comment: Although this also leads me to think: maybe I should have refreshed the page, so that the "I'm Done" button would have been enabled. Uhms.

Comment: Related: [Review queue bait-and-switch](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276278/review-queue-bait-and-switch?lq=1)

Comment: It's pretty frustrating that they haven't fixed this yet. For queues such as first posts and late answers, the `edit` counts as an action to complete the review item. If the post actually needs to be edited, but there's already one pending, there's no way to complete the review item properly. All you can do is perform the action outside of the queue, then come back and choose `No Action Needed`.

Answer (score 16):

They just forgot to execute `StackExchange.question.bindSuggestedEditPopupLinks()` on the page load, so I think it is a bug :)

`StackExchange.question.bindSuggestedEditPopupLinks()` would open the edit in the popup once clicking it (as it loads when you click `edit (1)` directly from the post (not in the review)), so when you close it, you are back to the review.

Comment: I am not very sure about what do you mean with `StackExchange.question.bindSuggestedEditPopupLinks()`. Could you elaborate the answer a bit more?

Comment: @fedorqui: It's implementation details in the Stack Exchange code, not something you need to understand, other than that nicael is answering that the SE code has a bug.

Comment: @fedorqui Thats just js *they* use (not my js) to make suggested edit load in the popup instead of going to another page, but they forgot to run it on the review load. I know it because I made observations before.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the explanation. So this means we are facing a bug. Editing the question to add [bug].

Comment: @fedorqui Why did you accept my answer? It is the bug  still and still not fixed (waiting official response).

Comment: True. I wanted to show that your answer solved the [support] question. But yes, as it is now a [bug], it needs to be [status-completed]. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: @nicael: Would this really work, or would trying to bring up the popup from within another review item mess up the review interface? Looking at [the code](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/review.en.js), it *seems* to assume that there's only one review item active on the page at any given time. (It should be possible to test this, given a suitable post under review with an active edit suggestion on it, by running the command you quoted in the browser's JS console.)