# Review queue bait-and-switch

Tags: bug, review-queues

You're reviewing a post in the **First Posts** review queue.

The post needs editing; and lo and behold, there happens be a suggested edit waiting for approval. You click the `edit(1)` link, which brings you to the usual edit review form. You review the edit, improve it, and save.

You're all done, so now the system brings you back, as expected, to the First Post review form for that post, so you can continue with other actions, such as upvoting, commenting etc. or click "I'm done" to go to the next post in the First Posts queue.

No! Wait a minute... *The system didn't do that!* It brought you to a new post in the **Suggested Edits** queue!

---

To me this is a bug. When done reviewing an edit in the First Post (or Late Answers or Low Quality Posts) queue, the system should bring you back to the post you were reviewing.

Instead it is currently doing something rather unexpected; throwing you off the track and into the Suggested Edits queue.

Comment: how do you know there is a pending suggested edit? does it show the `edit(1)` while you are in the review screen? I have to be honest I have never came across a situation like this even though I have done 1K+ first posts reviews O_o

Comment: Yes, the `edit(1)` shows. Maybe you just never noticed? This has happened to me I think three times in the past week or two; each time quite disconcerting.

Comment: yeah maybe I've just never noticed. It seems like a bug to me then.

Comment: I thought I had seen this before. [Indeed, I have.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274483/edit-suggested-on-late-answers-queue) It doesn't look like that post got a lot of dev attention, but it's been reported. :)

Comment: Why is this question is being voted for close?