# Clicking edit(1) took me away from the First Post review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

I was in the First Posts review queue and came across a post that linked to images because the user had insufficient rep to make them display as part of the post. I saw that someone had a pending edit because the link said `edit(1)`, so I clicked that to see if they were editing in the images for the user.

However this acted as a regular link and moved me from the First Post queue into suggested edits instead. This isn't what happens if there's no pending edit, in that case it would just allow me to make edits on the page itself. And on a regular question page a pending edit will create a pop up for me to review the edit in.

It would make more sense for the latter to happen as I'm not done editing the post but I'd like to check if the edit addresses the post to a satisfactory degree.

Comment: Same thing but different queue: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274483/edit-suggested-on-late-answers-queue

Comment: @NathanOliver Yet another year old bug that's not important enough to get attention. Oh well.

Comment: I would rather have them spending there time fixing the triage and HI queues then this little UI bug but I get what you mean.  This appears to be a couple minute fix at most.

Comment: +1, but I suspect this may be difficult to implement. The review code isn't really set up for having two reviews active on the same page at the same time (which is what bringing up the popup would involve). Returning you to the original queue after reviewing (or skipping) the edit suggestion might be doable, though.